# Как отключить переключение полей tab'ом

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю онлайн-редактор кода, соответственно, куда же без старого доброго TAB, но при нажатии, конечно же, фокус уходи с поля ввода.

Подскажите, есть ли какие-либо решения данной проблемы.

P.S. если это важно, то поле у меня- textarea

Comment: Могу показать как на Jqyery, если подходит конечно ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea)

```html
<textarea onkeydown="if(event.keyCode===9){var v=this.value,s=this.selectionStart,e=this.selectionEnd;this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e);this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;return false;}">
</textarea>
```

Comment: спасибо большое)